# Find the linear model of a latin square design

Tags: r, statistics, experimental-design

I want to get the equation of the linear model for the following experiment `mat` in latin square.

```
data <- c(12.5,11,13,11.4)
row <- factor(rep(1:2,2))
col <- factor(rep(1:2,each=2))
car <- c("B","A","A","B")
mat <- data.frame(row,col,car,data)
mat
# row col car data
# 1   1   1   B 12.5
# 2   2   1   A 11.0
# 3   1   2   A 13.0
# 4   2   2   B 11.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might recommend using a mixed model approach to this.

```
mat <- data.frame(data=c(12.5,11,13,11.4),
                  row=factor(rep(1:2,2)),
                  col=factor(rep(1:2,each=2)),
                  car=c("B","A","A","B"))
```

I'm using `lmerTest` because it will more easily provide you with (approximate) p-values

By default `anova()` uses the Satterthwaite approximation, or you can tell it to use the more accurate Kenward-Roger approximation.  In either case you can see that the denominator df are exactly, or nearly zero, and the p-value is either missing or very close to 1, indicating that your model doesn't make sense (i.e. even using the mixed model it's overparameterized).

```
library("lmerTest")
anova(m1 <- lmer(data~car+(1|row)+(1|col),data=mat))
anova(m1,ddf="Kenward-Roger")
##     Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF      DenDF F.value Pr(>F)
## car 0.0025  0.0025     1 9.6578e-06  2.0019 0.9999
```

Try for a bigger design:

```
set.seed(101)
mat2 <- data.frame(data=rnorm(36),
                  row=gl(6,6),
                  col=gl(6,1,36),
                  car=sample(LETTERS[1:2],size=36,replace=TRUE))
m2A <- lm(data~car+row+col,data=mat2)
anova(m2A)
## (excerpt)
##           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
## car        1  1.2571 1.25709  1.6515  0.211

m2B <- lmer(data~car+(1|row)+(1|col),data=mat2)
anova(m2B)
##     Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F.value Pr(>F)
## car  1.178   1.178     1 17.098    1.56 0.2285
anova(m2B,ddf="Kenward-Roger")
##     Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F.value Pr(>F)
## car  1.178   1.178     1 17.005  1.1029 0.3083
```

It surprises me a little bit that the `lm` and `lmerTest` answers are so far apart here -- I would have thought this was an example where there was a well-formulated "classic" answer -- but I'm not sure.  Might be worth following up on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) or Google.

Answer (score 1):

```
fit <- lm(data~row+col+car,mat)
coef(fit)
# (Intercept)        row2        col2        carB 
#       12.55       -1.55        0.45       -0.05
```

So the effect of the `row` factor is -1.55, the effect of the `col` factor is 0.45, and the effect of the `car` factor is -0.05. The intercept term is the value of `data` expected when al the factors are at the first level (`row=1`, `col=1`, `car=A`).

Notice that your design is over-specified: you have only 4 pieces of data, which is enough to specify the effects of two factors and their interaction, but you have set it up so that `car` is the interaction. So there are no degrees of freedom left for error.

Comment: if I increase the size of the square, then I'll row2, row3, ... rowN . Will be all coefficients in the model ? And how will be your interpretation? Thanks.